# How to ignore first word of a line while grepping from a file in perl?

Tags: perl

```
sub get_info () {

    open(FILE,"file.txt") or die "Could not open file";
    my @list = grep /\bWarning\b/, <FILE>;
    $count = 0;
    chomp @list;
    $list[$count] =~ s/^\S+\s*//;
    #do something; 
    $count++;
}

file.txt - 
Warning: New layer 256 is added
Warning: Layer deleted
Warning: New layer 301 is added
```

I want to ignore the 'Warning' word from every line.

But it is hiding the word 'Warning' only from the first sentence.

Am I incrementing $count properly?

Comment: I think you need to a loop?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are doing the replacement only for `$count=0`. Therefore only first index is getting modified.

```
$list[$count] =~ s/^\S+\s*//g;
```

You have not used any loop so `count` does not make sense.

**Solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_info{    
    open(FILE,"file.txt") or die "Could not open file";
    my @list = grep /\bWarning\b/, <FILE>;
    my $count = 0;
    foreach (@list) {
        $list[$count] =~ s/^\S+\s*//g;
        $count++;
    }
    print @list;
    #do something;
}

get_info();
```

**Output:**

```
New layer 256 is added
Layer deleted
New layer 301 is added
```

**Improvements:** Used 3 args open, removed grep and search replace, added while loop to read file line by line

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list;
sub get_info{
    open(my $fh, "<", "file.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";
    while(<$fh>){
        chomp;
        if (/^Warning:(.*)/){
            push @list, $1;
        }
    }
    print @list;
    #do something;
}

get_info();
```

Comment: Or just `@list = map { s/^Warning: // } grep /\bWarning\b/ <FILE>`

Comment: @tripleee, I think you need a comma after the `grep` arg and an `r` on that `s///r` or it'll return the count of substitutions, not the `$_` string.